# Find range $\sin^2\left(x\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\right)$

Tags: functions

What is the range of $\sin^2\left(x\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\right)$?

Comment: Depends what the domain is.

Comment: You can always try plotting the function to gain some intuition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First we find the range of $|x\sin{\frac{1}{x}}|$. For $|x| \leq1$, we clearly have the range $[0,\sin1]$. For $x>1$, we know this function is strictly increasing, and we have $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}x\sin\frac{1}{x}=1$ . Thus the range of $|x\sin{\frac{1}{x}}|$ is $[0,1]$, and so the range of $\sin^2(x\sin{\frac{1}{x}})$ is $[0,\sin^2{1}]$

Answer (score 0):

Using L'hopital, we see that the maximum of $x\sin(1/x)$ is $1$. The function also has SEVERAL zeros. It has a few points that are below the $x$-axis but, when we take the sine squared, it becomes irrelevant.

Thus stating, the range is $[0,\sin^2(1)]$ .